# TypeError: t(...).success is not a function - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the error `TypeError: t(...).success is not a function`. I did some searched but could understand why it causes this error on my case.

My JS code looks like below. What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting this error?

```
var app = angular.module('PriceListEditModule', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('PriceListEditController', ["$scope", "$q", function ($scope, $q) {

    GetBrands();

    function GetBrands() {
        $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: '/GetBrands'
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.brands = data;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
        });
    }
}]);
```

and the error is like below

```
jquery:1 TypeError: t(...).success is not a function
    at i (jquery:1)
    at new <anonymous> (jquery:1)
    at Object.invoke (jquery:1)
    at v.instance (jquery:1)
    at pt (jquery:1)
    at p (jquery:1)
    at p (jquery:1)
    at jquery:1
    at jquery:1
    at p.$eval (jquery:1)
```

Comment: why down vote??

Comment: errors from minified code aren't useful. Version numbers are useful.

Comment: what am I supposed to do?

Comment: use non-minified code when debugging. You are debugging, right?

Comment: I am trying to debug but couldnt succeed to debug JS

Comment: Now it gives me this "ReferenceError: $http is not defined"

Comment: seems like an accurate error message.

Comment: depends on your angularjs version.

Comment: Inject $http in you controller, next to $q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular does not have success with http.

[$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

And you are not including $http as a reference in your controller.

```
app.controller('PriceListEditController', 
    ["$scope", "$q", "$http", function ($scope, $q, $http) {
```

You really should be using a service for http calls and not doing it in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Change it with

In your service (where $http is defined), create a method

```
getBrands = function(){
    $http.get('/GetBrands', {})
        .then(function (result) {
            return result.data;
        });
}
```

and call it from your controller with

```
getBrands(data).then(function(data){
    //do some error checking and then assign
    $scope.brands = data;
})
```

Angular http is a little different from jQuery ajax call and the code you posted looks very similar to an ajax call rather than an angular's service call. Angular doesn't support calls backs with this syntax.

Comment: jquery:1 ReferenceError: $http is not defined

Comment: Better include $http service before writing any code that makes service calls.

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of angular. According to their [v1.5.11 documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.11/docs/api/ng/service/$http)

> **Deprecation Notice**
>
> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated and will be removed in v1.6.0. Use the standard then method
>   instead.

This means if you have an earlier version you will be using something like:

```
 $http({
     url: "/url",
     method: 'GET',
}).success(function (result) {
     //do success
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    //do error
});
```

Or if you have a version 1.6.0 or newer you will use:

```
 $http({
     url: "/url",
     method: 'GET',
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

if `$http` is not defined, you did not inject it into your controller. Inject it into your controller like:

```
app.controller('controller', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){}])
```